# Rcpp instead of mapply in model validation for many subsets

Tags: validation, glm, mapply

Let's say that we have specified N number of train datasets (80:20 division) and we want to retrieve a two element list with pvalues and coefficients from glm model, for each train dataset. The code reproducing this example is as follows:

```
library(parallel)
library(caret)

# prepare dataset
data(iris)
iris <- iris[!iris$Species == "setosa", ]

# create validation folds
set.seed(12345)
folds <- createDataPartition(y = iris$Species, times = 100, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)

# glm model expression
model.expr.tr <- expression(glm(formula = Species ~ Sepal.Length,
                                data = dtr,
                                family = binomial(link = "logit")))

# glm elements that will be validated
val_part <- list(coefs = expression(summary(eval(model.expr.tr))$coefficients[, 1]),
                 pvals = expression(summary(eval(model.expr.tr))$coefficients[, 4]))

# lapply with mapply for validation results
val_results <- lapply(val_part, function(x){
  mapply(function(i){
    trindex <- rownames(iris) %in% folds[, i]
    dtr <- iris[trindex, ]
    eval(x)
  },
  i = 1:100)
})
```

As you are aware, the longest part is running the model summary through all of train datasets, especially if we choose more than 100 of them. In your opinion, is there any way to speed up this process? Of course I am aware of parLapply / mcmapply options but what about some kind of Rcpp speed up in this case? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you profiled your code? In your example the main time seems to be taken up by `glm.fit` followed by `stats::model.frame`. I don't know any readymade solutions, but you could look into http://bwlewis.github.io/GLM/.

Comment: How did you manage to profile so "deep"? I have been trying this with profvis and I did not get se detailed results.

Comment: I used `profvis` via the menu in RStudio. In the GUI for the resulting profile I went to 'Data' and drilled down.

Comment: It's not a question for Rcpp so I will remove the tag.

Comment: Actually it somehow is because I asked whether there is a possibility for "Rcpp speed up in this case" :).